# request.getParameter() returns null after submitting the form

Tags: html, jsp

I dont know whats wrong!

filename: test2.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form  id="n1" method="POST" action="alter.jsp" />
    <input id="iditem" type="hidden"  value="213" />
    <input id="name1" type="hidden" value="123" />
    <input type="submit" value="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

filename: alter.jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String itemid = request.getParameter("iditem");
String name1 = request.getParameter("name1");
%>
<html><body>test<%= itemid %> + <%= name1 %></body></html>
```

after submitting the form the 2nd page only shows "test null null"

Comment: You should follow a tutorial, `form`'s need `name` to send `value`, not `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter name is set using the `name` attribute. Your form controls don't have `name`s so they won't be successful (i.e. won't submit any data).

The `id` attribute is used for client side operations such as:

- Linking to with a fragment identifier
- Associating a `<label>` with a form control
- Targeting using CSS
- Selecting using JavaScript and DOM

Comment: Thanks! I thought my laptop was the problem sinces my other files is working. I tried using javascript for my input and thought that id and name works the same and didnt notice